# Python Summing characters from multiple lines of various lengths

Tags: python, recursion

I want a function that iterates through each list item below and if 
the item does not being with a '>', I want the function to count the 
characters in each line then sum them all together'''
'''
My first issue is I dont know how to use a startswith() type function with a list of strings
My second issue is I don't know how to sum up all the lines together
This function needs to work on lines with any number of characters.

example list

`one_seq = ['>JM_001 hypo pr\n', 'MQGNQST\n', 'HLR\n']`

Recursive code I am trying to put together

```
def get_seq_length(seq):
    if line in seq line.startswith('>'):
        return sum(seq)
    else:
        length = get_seq_length(len(seq))
        return length

get_seq_length(one_seq)
```

Comment: By each line, do you mean each element in the list? Such as `'MQGNQST\n'`? Can you add your expected outputs?

Comment: First, this is not a naturally recursive problem.    Second, you seem to be trying to write a `for` loop and an `if` condition in one statement -- you need to separate these in your mind.

Comment: Please clarify your problem.  You don't sum characters or lines; you sum numbers.  Are you trying to add the lengths of the lines that don't start with a `>` character, perhaps?

Comment: Whatever the problem might be, I suggest that you work from the bottom up, writing one or two lines of code at a time, testing the results.  Solve the tiniest problem first, then use that solution to solve a larger problem.  Your posted code dies with a syntax error on the second line, so I'm not sure what aspect of this you want us to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think this code needs to be recursive, try this:

```
sum([len(x) for x in one_seq if not x.startswith(">")])
```

For each element that doesn't start with a ">" it will count the number of characters with the len function. It then adds all of the lengths of the relevant elements up to give you the total

Answer (score 0):

Here's something from IDLE that will get you the first character of a string:

```
>>> s = "asdf"
>>> s[0]
'a'
```

You can access characters in a string like elements of an array. You'll get an error if you try to access something out of bounds.

Thus, if you know your string has at least one element,

```
for item in your_list:
    if item[0] == '>':
        #Do Something
```

And if you need the total length of strings who aren't prefixed with `>`,

```
count = 0
for item in your_list:
    if item[0] != '>':
        count = count + len(item)
```

Comment: @rahlf23 It answers the first part of his question, while I read up on the second part once again.

Answer (score 0):

This function returns the length of all entries that do not start with >. It doesn't need to be recursive, it just loops through the list.

```
def get_seq_length(seq):
    count = 0
    for line in seq:
        if !line.startswith('>'):
            count += len(line)
    return count

get_seq_length(one_seq)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you want to count the number of characters in each element (or line) in your list (`one_seq`) of lines. To count the number of characters in a given line, you can use `len()`, and then leverage a list comprehension and `sum()` to add the number of characters for each line together. From your OP, it sounds like you only want to do so if **at least 1** of the lines in your list does not begin with `>`, for which you can use `any()`. This should do it:

```
sum([len(line) for line in one_seq if any(not l.startswith('>') for l in one_seq)])
```

Testing a few examples:

```
one_seq = ['>JM_001 hypo pr\n', 'MQGNQST\n', 'HLR\n']
one_seq = ['>JM_001 hypo pr\n', '>MQGNQST\n', '>HLR\n']
one_seq = ['>JM_93rnfo pr\n', '>MQGT\n', 'HKHASDKN\n']
```

Yields:

```
28
0
29
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect you may find it useful to have the sequence ID as well as the sequence length. This uses a list comprehension which is identical to a previous answer but it also gets rid of the newline characters (`\n`).

```
one_seq = ['>JM_001 hypo pr\n', 'MQGNQST\n', 'HLR\n']
seq_id,seq_len = process_seq(one_seq)

def process_seq(seq_lines):

    # using first line, remove >, remove \n and split at spaces taking the first part
    seq_id = seq_lines[0].replace('>','').rstrip().split(" ")[0]

    # get the sequence length:
    seq_len = sum(len(line.rstrip()) for line in seq_lines if not line.startswith('>'))

    return (seq_id,seq_len)
```

Comment: can you tell me how to do this for a file with multiple seqs? I want to make a list of all the sequence lengths in a file of multiple sequences